# Cisco ASA 5505 - InterVLAN NAT Exemptions Implementation not working

Tags: nat, cisco-asa

Short version is we cannot communicate between our subnets.

We have a Cisco ASA 5505 we are using for our network router.  We have a Netgear L2 switch behind that with 10 vlans. Each VLAN is on its own subnet.  (10.0.10.x/24, 10.0.11.x/24, etc)

So ASA >>> Switch >>> Hosts

We have PAT for each subnet to our outside interface.  Each subnet NATs out properly.

I have NAT exemption enabled for 2 of the subnets (eventually I will need all, but am just testing at the moment).

Config is here: http://pastebin.com/pDsG7hsh

I have tried multiple ways for the NAT exemption to allow all traffic from our inside VLANS.  At this point in time I am trying to get "Engineering" to communicate with all hosts on "AuthUser".

I can ping some hosts, but not as many as if I am directly on the interface.  I can reach a port 80 service, but not 443.  I cannot access anything via hostname or NetBIOS.

What am I missing to allow higher security level interfaces to fully communicate with lower security level interfaces?

Thx!

Comment: Why route VLAN traffic through the ASA when you can route it through the layer 3 switch?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it is a layer 2 switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at
[Cisco ASA 5540_outside to inside traffic NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/429154/cisco-asa-5540-outside-to-inside-traffic-nat/429167#429167)
and
[Cisco ASA 5505 Voice/Data VLANs not pinging/routing](https://serverfault.com/questions/392730/cisco-asa-5505-voice-data-vlans-not-pinging-routing/392734#392734)
i think this should solve your connection and ACL question.

Why you wan't use Netbios Name Resolution instead of DNS?